# False fluent validation error goes away after IIS restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, fluentvalidation

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I use Fluent Validation to validate my models.Please take a look at my model:

```
[Table("INWARDDOCUMENTS")]
public class InwardDocument{
    .......................
    [Column("DOCDATE")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"),Display(Name="Document date")]
    public DateTime? DocDate { get; set; }
    ........................
}
```

And here's the fluent validation part:

```
 RuleFor(doc => doc.InwardDocument.DocDate.Value.Date).LessThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now.Date).When(x=>x.InwardDocument.DocDate!=null).WithMessage("Document date cannot be greater than the current date");
```

Overall it works fine, but in average every 3 weeks I get this validation error although the model value is correctly entered. As you can see, I compare the date part of the model with the date part of today, if a date is entered. So no hours or minutes are involved. I enter the same information in debug mode and don't receive this validation error. The only cure is to restart the IIS. Just that is enough to have the problem go away. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you instantiating your validators?

I'd highly suggest you not reference DateTime.Now directly in your validator's constructor.

If your validator is instantiated as a singleton (which the default MVC integration will do for performance reasons), then the value of DateTime.Now ends up being cached too, so you'll end up getting weird results.

You need to invoke this lazily- use the overload of LessThanOrEqualTo that takes a Func[T] instead:

```
RuleFor(x => x.whatever).LessThanOrEqual(x => DateTime.Now.Date);
```

...or use a Must rule instead:

```
RuleFor(x => x.whatever).Must(val => val <= DateTime.Now.Date);
```

This way, the value of DateTime.Now is looked up every time the validator is invoked, rather than the that DateTime.Now held at the time the object was created.

Comment: Yes the instantiation is singleton. But what I am curious about is if the caching is the reason, then shouldn't this happen everyday as the date cached today is already going to be outdated tomorrow? And when you say you would suggest not to` reference DateTime.Now directly in the validator`, where do you suggest I do?

Comment: When I said don't reference DateTime.Now directly, I meant reference it lazily using a func as in the example.